# Drawbacks of increasing K in k-fold Cross-Validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, validation

I would like to know if there is any drawback to increasing `K` in `K-fold CrossValidation`, except the computational one.

Answer (score 4):

An issue with larger K is that you have larger training sets that overlap more, leading to a stronger dependence between the results in the K folds. There is always a trade-off between (a) using more information in larger folds to achieve better results that are closer to using the full data and (b) keeping dependence between the folds low because if dependence is large, you can't learn much new from another fold.

I had for a long time thought that larger K is always better, but Peter Buehlmann made me aware of this, and I think that he believed, at least at the time (20 years ago), that actually smaller K might be better. Unfortunately I never thoroughly researched whether there is literature on that issue and what it says. I did once supervise a student project exploring it by simulation, but the results were inconclusive one way or the other, and the scope was very limited.

Now the qualification here is this: Obviously if you run K-folds CV *just once*, larger K needs more computation time, and my intuition still would say that this is better than smaller K, because the larger number of folds may just be worth paying the larger degree of dependence.

However note that you can randomly split a data set into K folds more than once, and you could compare lower and higher K *standardising the computing time*, i.,e., running more replicates for smaller K so that ultimately the computation time is the same. I believe that Buehlmann's comment that smaller K may be better may have referred to this version of comparison, and this was also what we tried out in the inconclusive student project mentioned above.

I think at the time Buehlmann could only point me to theory that investigated running *all possible* partitions into K folds, which is practically not feasible (I also forgot where to find this, as I didn't find it much enlightening, except that you could see theoretically how larger dependence could be an issue for larger K).

So from my point of view the issue isn't clearly decided (I'd be happy to see any response that could cite more contemporary literature on this). Buehlmann has a point there, but to what extent this point outweighs the advantage to have more larger folds isn't obvious.

Based on this, choosing smaller K but investing some more computation time to run more replicates may well be a viable option (more so if your data set is large).

Comment: "An issue with larger K is that you have larger test sets that overlap more" - was this meant to read "larger training sets" instead?

Comment: @Firebug Thanks, changed.

Comment: IMHO whether the larger overlap is good or bad crucially depends on whether the CV results are used to approximate performance of THE MODEL trained by the given algorithm on the whole data set at hand (we basically assume there is no relevant difference between CV training sets and whole data set) vs. population behaviour (how good is my training algorithm for such problems where we assume the CV training sets to approximate new independent samples, there low k may make this a less bad approximation).

Comment: Regarding fixed number of total surrogate models: I almost always run at least some repetitions, since that allows me to better separate model instability in the CV estimates from case-to-case variance uncertainty.